# Finding shortest calculation of the sum of a subset of a group, given sums for other previously summed subsets

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, convex-optimization, subset-sum, integer-lattice

Say $S=\{g\in G\}$ is a set of elements in an abelian group $G$ whose group operation $(+)$ is expensive to compute. Given a subset $T\subset S$, we want to compute the sum of $T$'s elements, $\sigma_T=\sum_{g\in T}g$. Say we have a collection of other subsets of $S$, $U=\{T_i\}$, for which the sums $\sigma_{T_i}=\sum_{g\in T_i}g$ are already known. We can assume $U$ contains the singleton subsets of $S$, since $\sigma_{\{g\}}=g$. Hence   $\sigma_T$ can always be expressed as a linear combination of the $\sigma_{T_i}$'s, namely $\sum_{g\in T}\sigma_{\{g\}}=\sum_{g\in T}g=\sigma_T$. I'd like to find the linear combination$\sum_i a_i\sigma_{T_i}=\sigma_T$, which minimizes $\sum_i|a_i|$, i.e., which computes the sum with the least number of group operations.

It seems likely that the problem of actually finding this optimum is NP-complete, so I'm looking for good heuristics, ideally with some reasonable bound on the distance from optimality. Also, any references to papers discussing this problem would be great. Finally, storing the $\sigma_{T_i}$'s is somewhat expensive for me, too, so I'm also interested in heuristics for deciding which $\sigma_{T_i}$'s should be stored, given a sequence $\{T_1, T_2, \ldots\}$, and fixed costs for storage, retrieval and group operations.

Comment: If your algorithm does not evaluate the group operation ($+$), then this reduces a problem about integer vectors.  In particular, if $S$ has $k$ elements, you can view each $T$ as a characteristic vector $\chi_T \in \{0,1\}^k$ of length $k$, and then the question is to find $a_i$ that minimizes $\sum_i |a_i|$ subject to $\sum_i a_i \chi_{T_i} = \chi_T$.  If the algorithm does evaluate the group operation, then you have to model how slow the group operation is and talk about how you want to define its complexity.